# Facebook API Request Limits in Development Access for Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently experiencing an issue with the Facebook Marketing API, specifically regarding the API request limits under the development access level. I have noticed a peculiar behavior where the headers in my API responses consistently show zero utilization, but after some time, I receive an error stating "User request limit reached."

The headers in question are as follows:

```
X-Ad-Account-Usage: 
{"acc_id_util_pct":0,"reset_time_duration":0,"ads_api_access_tier":"development_access"}

X-App-Usage: {"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}
```

Despite these headers indicating no usage (0% utilization across all parameters), I am still encountering the error that suggests I have reached the user request limit.

I would like to understand if this behavior is expected under the development access tier. Is it normal for these limits to be reported as zero in the headers, yet still encounter a limit reached error?

Comment: That's a bug on FB side. You can follow this thread: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/127386880455377/